# empty mysql_error.log file in xampp server.

Tags: xampp, mysql-error-1064

When I try starting my MySql, nothing actually happens. It doesn't respond at all.
Then I tried checking into the 'data' folder of mysql in xampp, i found no mysql.error_log file in it.
What possibly can b the reason for that?
Empty mysql_error.log file in Xampp server. What should I do now?

Comment: In your C:\xampp\mysql\data , you find any file named ibdata1 ?

Comment: Yeah I deleted the ibdata file from the folder.. Anything more can I do? Please help!

Comment: Try restart xampp after deleting it, even if you don't solve the problem convey, so that i shall look forward